# Как вывести переменную в div?

Tags: javascript

Нужно вывести значение переменной в блок div.
Есть код:

```
<script>
    function summa() {
        var i = 1;
        document.getElementById('summa2').innerHTML = i;}
</script>
```

html:

```
<div id="summa2"></div>
```

Вывести таким способом не получается.

Comment: попробуйте еще раз

Comment: Консоль не показывает ошибок?

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку "show" выдает 1.
Получается все правильно работает. И вывести значение также получается.
Учитывая что код воспроизводится на стороннем ресурсе (не в Вашем локальном браузере) - проблема кроется у Вас на локальной машине. Для понимания как с этим бороться необходима дополнительная информация: 1. Какой браузер используете? 2. Консоль какие ошибки выдает?

Comment: @Igor, откатил на первую версию, так как неизвестно какой код у автора.

Comment: @Alex Demonov ваш вопрос рассматривался тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677799/how-to-append-data-to-div-using-javascript

Answer (score -1):

Так должно работать!!!

```
document.getElementById('summa2').innerText = i;
```